# Add the elements of $b to the end of array $a in php

Tags: php

I have 2 arrays.
I want to add the elements of $b to the end of $a.  I checked google, nothing.

```
$a=array(1,2,3);
$b=array(4,5,6);
array_push($a,$b);

print_r($a);
```

My goal is to make $a=(1,2,3,4,5,6) but the above doesn't work correctly...any ideas?

Comment: `$c = array_merge($a, $b);` - Could not post this as an answer because it was too short. [Second result on Google BTW.](http://www.google.com/search?q=add+elements+of+two+arrays+php)

Comment: I used different search terms, but yes, I can confirm your method works, thanks!

Comment: "I checked google, nothing" means you should intelligently adapt your search terms. Never satisfy yourself that Google does not have the answer, as this is negligibly unlikely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_merge` for that.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

```
$c = array_merge($a, $b);
```

$c = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);

Answer (score -2):

Use [array_merge()](http://php.net/array_merge)

```
$a = array(1,2,3);
$b = array(4,5,6);
$c = array_merge($a, $b);

print_r($c);
```

You can't use [array operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php): `+` as [xzyfer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/233633/xzyfer) pointed out.
It will do a union and only works when the keys don't overlap.